# Refresh in-mem data cache in ASP.NET WebAPI controller periodically?

Tags: asp.net, caching, asp.net-web-api, controller

I have a website built up with ASP.NET WebAPI and hosted on Azure. It talks with SQL server, to improve user perceived page loading performance I added a in memory data cache in its controller, because the refreshing logic is lazy, so first user will experience a long loading time.

Now I want to actively refresh the cache, can I schedule a thread/task in controller to periodically refresh the cache (I have set the website as 'always on' so the app pool won't dispose it)? Is there any ready-to-use libraries I can use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Azure, but for on premises you can use Global.ascx file's Application_Start method to load cache initially.

You can use same global.asax file to schedule a timer to call a method periodically, in this method you can write logic to invalidate and reload cache.
See how to use Timer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx5easy.aspx):

You can use HttpRuntime.Cache to store cached data.

In Addition to make sure your object should be disposed and no background thread should be running when the Application gets closed (both planned/unexpectedly)

Also read about IRegisteredObject interface which will help you to dispose object before application get closed.

Let me know if you need more info on how to implement it, you need to provide more info for this.

Comment: I also have a similar requirement. I am using MemoryCache  for caching in my web api. Now I want to create an API end point which refreshes all cache from the server where my API is deployed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try Quartz.Net is simple and very nice tool to schedule/manage task.